# OSX10.10.4 installation. Failed to process package 'catkin'

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using homebrew to install ROS indigo on OS X 10.10.4 with 'Desktop Install (recommended): ROS, rqt, rviz, and robot-generic libraries', and I've gone to this step without error:

```
 ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

the error log is:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/Users/xgwang/Workspace/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Trace/BPT trap: 5
<== Failed to process package 'catkin':
  Command '['make', 'cmake_check_build_system']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /Users/xgwang/Workspace/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && make cmake_check_build_system

Command failed, exiting.
```

What should I do to finish the installation? Thanks for any advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214363/osx10.10.4-installation.-failed-to-process-package-%27catkin%27/) by [gnhf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23302/gnhf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You installed something from Homebrew which installed the jpeg formula. This formula is not compatible with the version of libjpeg in the System, so when you try to use something which is built against the System version of libjpeg, you have jpeg installed from Homebrew, and `/usr/local/lib` is on the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` then you'll get this error. Individually all of these things are fine, but together they cause an issue. To address this I usually unlink libjpeg, libpng, and libtiff from Homebrew:

```
$ brew unlink jpeg libpng libtiff
```

This will work around your issue there, but anything installed with Homebrew which utilized jpeg from Homebrew, for example opencv, then you'll get a similar error when you try to run something that uses it. To address this I usually use `otool -L` to figure out which executables and library refer to `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg...dylib` and `install_name_tool` to change that to `/usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg...dylib`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gnhf](https://answers.ros.org/users/23302/gnhf/) on 2015-07-23**:
Yes, I have jpeg libpng libtiff in my brew list, and I installed opencv through Homebrew.
I get this after `otool -L /usr/local/lib/libjpeg*`

```
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

So should I use install_name_tool to change them?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-07-24**:
You need to use install_name_tool to change the references that *other* shared libraries and executables have to `/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib` (for example `libopencv...dylib`) rather than making changes to `libjpeg.8.dylib` itself.